# SDL_Event e; passing to function

Tags: c++, c, sdl

What is e in

```
SDL_Event e;
```

How to pass e from one function to another function then to another function.
is it possible?

Basically is e bool or int

```
bool x_out_window()
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while( !quit )
    {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            quit = true;
            else
            detect_key_press(e.type);
        }

    }
}

bool detect_key_press(e.type)
{
    //SDL_Event e;
    if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
    {
        //Select surfaces based on key press
        switch( e.key.keysym.sym )
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP ];
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN ];
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT ];
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT ];
            break;

            default:
            gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ];
            break;
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
    }
}
```

I am sorry if this is a silly question but i am unable to understand the concept, i am novice in coding.

Comment: _"Basically is e `bool` or `int`"_ - Neither, it's an `SDL_Event`

Comment: `e` specifies a variable of type [`SDL_Event`](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlevent.html). To pass it to a function just let it have an appropriate signature: `void function2 (const SDL_Event& e)`

Comment: C or C++? Don't randomly throw tags into a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your function 2 as

```
void funtion2(SDL_Event e){
  //...
}
```

in C++ you need to provide a type for both the function (probably `void` here) and all the parameters (a `SDL_Event` named `e` here)